# Синтаксическая неупорядоченность предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Есть предложение на английском и перевод (который является подстрочником и отличается синтаксической непорядочностью).

Я исправил перевод. Меня интересует, насколько грамотно, с синтаксической точки зрения, звучит мой перевод.

P.S. Понимаю, что это не форум переводчиков. Но прошу проверить лишь русский синтаксис.

Anyone who has contact with customers is a sales person — that includes the telephonist who answers the phone and the service engineer who calls to repair a machine. So that probably includes you!

> *Всякий, кто связывается с клиентами, является продавцом — это включает телефонистку, которая отвечает на телефонные звонки, и обслуживающего инженера, который приходит чинить машину. Так что это, наверное, включает и вас!*

**Всякий, кто имеет дело с клиентами, является продавцом. Это относится и к телефонистке,  которая отвечает на телефонные звонки, и к обслуживающему инженеру, который приходит что-то починить.**

Comment: "синтаксическая непорядочность" — забавная опечатка :)

Comment: "Всякий" лучше заменить на "каждый", а в остальном всё корректно, я считаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу две проблемы: избыточность и слегка странное сочетание "являться — относиться" (я бы сказал, что быть кем-то — отношение только с точки зрения формальной логики, а не человеческой речи). Если срезать лишнее, получится так:

> Каждый, кто имеет дело с клиентами, является продавцом: и телефонистка, принимающая звонки, и инженер, который приходит что-нибудь починить.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Мне понравился ваш вариант. Но при таком варианте теряется последнее предложение. Как его перевести?

Comment: @plotnikov.tosha2016 Тут много из чего можно выбрать, чтобы не было повторений в последующем тексте: "Продавцом, может быть, являетесь и вы!", "Возможно, вы тоже продавец!". Главное, не запутать читателя чем-то вроде "Им являетесь и вы" (инженером?) или "Вы один из них" (клиент? продавец? телефонистка?).

Comment: Спасибо за прояснение!